# Rails bad URI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I get rid of special characters with some regular expression?

I have a search_controller in which I do this with CGI.escape.

```
def index
  @page     = search_params[:page] || 1
  @per_page = search_params[:per_page] || 20
  @query    = URI.parse(CGI.escape(search_params[:query]).gsub("%40", "@").gsub("%C3%9F", "ß").gsub("%C3%BC", "ü"))
```

But I want to do it with some kind of regexp instead of white listing all the other characters I need besides the ones which break the search.

Comment: You're escaping, then unescaping?

Comment: `gsub` uses regular expressions.

Comment: Could you please clarify what are you want to do with `query` parameter?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm escaping and then adding back @ and 2 german signs.

Comment: Instead of "whitelisting" all german characters I need, I was thinking I can achieve this with a regexp to get rid only of special characters that break the search. Like ] or [ etc.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you are doing some sort of pagination I highly recommend to use a pagination gem like *kaminari* or *will_paginate*.

If you are escaping the query for security reasons, what you are doing here is *blacklisting* some special chars, doing so is not recommended, the best way would be instead doing some sort of *whitelisting* of permitted characters.

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#whitelists-versus-blacklists

A possible regular expression to only match characters could be

```
query.gsub(/([\W]+)/, '')
```

This matches characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.

But I wouldn't recommend to use a simple regex like this in production.